# Coupon code appearing but not included in calculations for Magento site

Tags: magento

[image]

This image sums it up.  The discount code is being recognized and appears in all total boxes from the view cart page all the way through to the order appearing in the admin area.  However it is not appearing in the calculations.

Anyone have any clue what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the mage_tax module enabled on your backend?

`System > Configuration > Advanced > Enable the Mage_Tax module`

If so, and you're using Mage 1.4 try this fix instead

1. create the following folders in your Magento distro: `app/code/local/Mage/CatalogRule`/Model
2. copy `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/CatalogRule/Model`
3. open the new/copied file and go to line 105. Change this code:

from

```
if ($observer->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
    $gId = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerGroupId();
} elseif ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
    $gId = $product->hasCustomerGroupId();
} else {
    $gId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
}
```

to

```
if ($observer->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
    $gId = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerGroupId();
} elseif ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
    $gId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
} else {
    $gId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
}
```